# How to restrict node view to users by registration date?

Tags: users

In short I'm trying to find a solution to:

1. Restrict view access to certain custom node types by the date the
   user registered
2. The user would be able to see restricted content created in
   the month they registered and any future month while their user
   account is active, but nothing before the date the account was created
3. There is existing content restrictions and
   functionality for the same users on the same content. Only certain
   roles can see selected node types and this is selected when the user
   is created (manually). This is managed by
   https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess

This website has restricted content that only members (registered users) can see.

These fall into several categories and the content is divided into these categories too.  Depending on the type of member and what you been given access too, you will only be able to see that content. This is managed by Node Access and works well and as intended.

A new requirement has now popped up after the fact where this content access should be further restricted. It should honour the previously mentioned restrictions managed by nodeaccess but now apply additional parameters.  All these are relevant to the month in which the user's account is created:

1. Restricted content posted before must not be available
2. Restricted content posted after must be available (and future
   content too, but still honouring the nodeaccess restrictions)

I'm fairly capable with Drupal dev, but cannot write code or rules which I think this requirement is leaning towards.

Anyone got any suggestion that will work or can perhaps point me in the right direction to get a start?

Answer (score 1):

You need use this hook https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7

So in your module you need code smth like this

```
function YUORMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = is_string($node) ? $node : $node->type;

  if ($op == 'view') {
    global $user; // get current user
    // check user register date
    if ($user->created < $node->created) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }

// Returning nothing from this function would have the same effect.
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I read up on creating a module and created a new module using the above code. To enable the module I had to remove the last "}" as it threw an error when trying to enable the module.

The module is now enabled but seems to have no affect. I.e. "old content", restricted content created before the user creation date is still displayed. I get the following error in the server logs:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /sites/all/modules/node_access_byregdate/node_access_byregdate.module on line 18

Comment: you are right) i fixed code. use it)

Comment: sorry, hit enter before I'd added the full story.

Comment: i edited code. use it once again. http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/146527/10563

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the time and effort. I made the change and the module enables and re-enables just fine now. However it has no affect on the restricted content. All restricted content is visible to a new user, where all restricted content before the user's creation date should be hidden from them.

Comment: Also, looking at the code and taking into account my limited knowledge, it looks like this would be very strict on the date, e.g. anything before 11/02 if they register today would be hidden. If possible I want to restrict content only from the month BEFORE they register, i.e. January in this case, and everything before that. Anything in Feb and the future is ok to display.

Comment: i gave you very basic idea, how to resolve your task.

Comment: If you use any extra modules, or need to implement more complex logic , add backend UI, etc, 5 lines of code will not be enough, or you may need to use other hooks, which control access to entity. so, my code its just a very basic idea.

Comment: No worries, thanks for your time. As I did mention I can't code myself hence the request for help ;) I'll ask over at the nodeaccess community see if they can help. Cheers